# I want to fix the size of the body with CSS to the initial size when the page first loads

Tags: html, css, css-animations, height, viewport

I want to fix the size of the body to the initial size (size when the page first loaded to prevent any changes to the it from elements that resize on animations).

How do i do this?

```
body {
  height: initial; /* This does not work */
}
```

and neither does this

```
body {
   height: 200vh;
}
```

EDIT -
This is the animation

```
.small-logo img {  /* This class is toggled in JS*/
    height: 40px;
    /* animation: name duration timing-function delay iteration-count direction fill-mode; */
    animation: shrink 1s ease;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes shrink {
    0% {
        height: 100px;
        top: -100px;
        opacity: 10%;
    }
    100% {
        height: 40px;
        top: 0px;
        opacity: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you include your animation it is much easier for us to understand how the behaviour from the animation is affecting the body height

Answer (score 1):

This is pure javascript solution if you want to fix size on initial load:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // find out your body's height and hardcode it programmaticaly:
  var height = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.height = height +"px"; 
}, false);
```

So, you do it after intial DOMContentLoaded event is executed and then fix body height.

Comment: Yes, but I was thinking of doing that as a last resort. Isn't there a way do this in CSS only?

Comment: I'm not sure you'll find CSS only solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at: `fit-content`, `max-content`, `min-content`.

`fit-content` sets the height of the element to its needed space. In order to "protect" the height you can use `max-height: fit-content` and/or `min-height: fit-content`.

Comment: No, non of these help. As they are all dynamic properties. I want the size of the body to be static and not change at all. i.e. if there is extra size if will remain at the bottom.

Comment: Ok. I don´t think this is possible with only css. But you can use a small js script. 
After dom is ready, you can read the height of the element like this: 
`let box = document.querySelector('.box');
 let width = box.offsetWidth;
 let height = box.offsetHeight;`
After this step you can set the min/max height of the element via js to this height.